# How to simulate a slow WAN speed

Tags: sql, odbc, ado, lag

Working on an Excel VBA project that sends data to an SQL server via ADO. In my office I have no issues but the users are based at locations where they use VSAT connections. Thus, the ping time go for 1-2 ms to 800 ms for lag.

I want to test my code's ADO Connection and Command Timeouts to make sure I have them set appropriately. Anyone have any tried and true code snippets that increase the CommandTimeout and ConnectionTimeout after a failed .open or .execute command?

I have seen via Google Search that many web developers use Fiddler but that looks like it will only work for HTTP-type connections.

Anyone have an idea that doesn't involve me creating my own VPN (I have no server) or re-configuring the SQL server, I'm not the owner.

Comment: In the end I just used the QoS feature on my Router to turn down my through put to about an 18k modem. Worked well for me.